# How to change the background color of the WebBrowser control before loading content?

Tags: colors, browser, activex, document, flicker

I have a page that contains a WebBrowser control that is frequently updating content. I am using a black background, but the default color before loading content of the WebBrowser is white. I can change it by loading a small HTML string with the background set to black but there is still a period of time when the WebBrowser appears as white so there is a sort of a flickering effect happening.

My question is this: is there a way to change the color of the underlying control of the WebBrowser?

I have tried a few solutions such as hiding the WebBrowser until the content has been loaded but none of these feel very elegant and don't work all that well.

Note: This exact question has been asked and answered before for WP7/Silverlight, but I need a solution for WPF/Winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. A form with a splitcontainer and a webbrowser. And a non-white background :-) The flickering was unbearable. Anyway, I had some success by taking the game-programming approach; put a timer on your form, let it call an update method X times per second. The update method evaluates a couple of conditions which determine  if the webbrowser should be made visible. Of course the update method must be lean and mean:

```
    private void OnPollForChanges(FormBrowseAllData inData)
    {

        webBrowser1.Visible = (mWebBrowserResizing == 0) && 
                    (!mWebBrowserLoading) && 
                    webBrowser1.ReadyState >= WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive;

        if (mWebBrowserResizing>0)
        {
            mWebBrowserResizing--;
        }
```

when you detect a resize or force a resize yourself, you simply hide the webbrowser for X updates:

```
    private void webBrowser1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mWebBrowserResizing = 5;
        webBrowser1.Visible = false;
    }
```

And when you do something that might cause a reload:

```
    private void SetHTML(string inHTML)
    {
        webBrowser1.Visible = false;
        mWebBrowserLoading = true;
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = inHTML;
    }
```

and:

```
    void OnWebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, 
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        mWebBrowserLoading = false;
    }
```

This reduces flicker to about 5% of what it was before. Of course these are just lame hacks and not proper solutions.

PS: there is some overlap between the use of mWebBrowserLoading and checking webBrowser1.ReadyState. Because in theory ReadyState should change in sync with mWebBrowserLoading, but anyway "Better safe than sorry" is the motto here.

Answer (score 4):

Not much you can do but prevent the window from getting visible until the browser has initialized itself.  A winforms solution:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value) {
        if (!this.IsHandleCreated) {
            CreateHandle();
            value = false;
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += initializationDone;
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<body bgcolor=#000000></body>";
        }
        base.SetVisibleCore(value);
    }
    private void initializationDone(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= initializationDone;
        this.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that .DocumentCompleted fires very late (after all remote images are loaded, etc), making the user wait unnecessarly long. I also tried .Navigated, which fires much earlier, but it still shows the white background briefly, so it fires to soon. The last alternative would be monitoring the .ReadyState property, but it requires continuely inspecting the value in a loop, since there is no event for it. I'm afraid that the constant polling of that value slows down the webbrowser control when it's trying to load. It's a shame there's no 'nice' way of fixing this.

Comment: Well, it doesn't take very long to load that document I pushed into DocumentText.  Whatever you are downloading from that server is going to take *way* longer.  Do one before the other, I gave you the trigger to start the real download.

Comment: It may be related to WPF, but when I create a TabItem containing a Webbrowser, and add the TabItem to the TabControl from within the .DocumentCompleted event, I still see the white flash, allthough the document is fully loaded. Is there some way to force a repaint first?

Comment: That's called "flicker", you see a white hole where the window goes before it has time to draw itself.  Very hard to get rid of in WPF.  A stupid trick is to set the window's Opacity property to 0.99.  Makes the hole black instead of white.

Comment: I guess the webbrowser skips all rendering untill it's actually visible, there must be some dirty p/invoke api's to force it to redraw in an invisible state, which should get rid of the 'delay' we see. Another cause could be that it's an wrapped ActiveX in a WPF window, I wish WPF had a 'native' HTML rendering component. Is it OK that I leave this question unanswered? I appreciate your answer, but I still have the ugly flash.