# windows Forms WebBrowser : Flicker Issue

Tags: windows, forms, webbrowser-control, flickr

I have added windows Forms WebBrowser control to splitter control. But when resizing WebBrowser control get flicker. I have searched a solution but still i cannot find. If Anyone know how to prevent this please help.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the background color of the WebBrowser control before loading content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938691/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-webbrowser-control-before-loading-cont)

Comment: Thanks Hans. Flicker only happen when resizing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable dublebuffering on the form.

```
this.SetStyle(
  ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
  ControlStyles.UserPaint |
  ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer,true);
```

Comment: The WebBrowser flickers, not the form.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan..It is not working. Hans is correct.Flicker happen in browser. not in form.